# When finding a child element with jQuery, the page is oddly jumping

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am getting this issue in Safari and Chrome... I think Firefox is working.

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(".featureSection").hover(function(){ 
$(this).stop(true, true).toggleClass("activeSection", 500);
$(this).find(".para").stop(true, true).fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Here is the section of HTML I am accessing:

```
<div class="featureSection clearfix">
    <h3>And...</h3>
    <div class="sectionTitle">

        <h1>Holiday Cards</h1>
        <img src="http://crm-newsletter.com/website/images_concierge/gift1.png" alt="" width="229" height="224" />
        <h4 class="para">After closing with your client a beautiful gift and customized thank you card will be sent out as appreciation for their business. </h4>

    </div><!--end sectionTitle -->
</div><!-- end featureSection -->
```

Here is the page:

[Page With Issue](http://www.crm-newsletter.com/website/concierge.html#)

Notice when you hover over a section, the entire page jumps down. This only happens on the first roll over, after that everything works fine. The jump stops when I remove the `.find` code, so I imagine this is causing this issue for some reason. Any solutions? Even if it is something entirely different but the same affect. Thanks.

Comment: Second attribute of JQuery `toggleClass` method should be boolean. In your case it is not needed at all.

Comment: @VisioN Though not tagged, I imagine he is using jqueryui's animated toggleClass where that is a duration.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Right, that may be. However it should be checked.

Comment: @VisioN, James is correct. I am using jQuery UI.

Comment: What should I check? I am trying to use the UI toggle class.

Comment: Note that the problem doesn't seem to exist in Firefox, but does exist in Chrome (for people who are testing/trying to help)

Comment: @GregPettit This is stated in the description. The very first thing said.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Doesn't seem to happen in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NuBkU/. W3 shows a few errors though http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crm-newsletter.com%2Fwebsite%2Fconcierge.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I finally solved this by wrapping the `<h4>` in a div tag and set the `.fadeToggle` on this. Not sure why it worked exactly, but it worked. Someone make this solution more thorough in an answer and I'll award it. Otherwise, I have to wait 6 hours to answer it myself.

Comment: @TommyCoffee So weird. I looked for it, honest I did, and somehow missed it. ;-)

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in my Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by wrapping the `<h4>` in a div tag and set the `.fadeToggle` on this. Not sure why it worked exactly, but it worked.

Comment: Your code is loaded with [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crm-newsletter.com%2Fwebsite%2Fconcierge.html%23&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) including a huge number of duplicate ID's (each `id` must be unique).  Your "fix" may only be a band aid where the root cause still lies elsewhere.